# Magento:Display SKU of associated products in Configurable product drop-down

Tags: magento

Hello i want to display in configurable product option with associated production sku,,currently it show product label and price.

i know currently only product label are coming from product .js but i want add sku of associated product[image]

Comment: where you want to show sku of associated product?

Comment: in associated product list dropdown

Comment: i want add sku of associated product in dropdown

Comment: dropdown options are coming from js/varien/configurable.js file.Need time to do that.

Comment: i know that,,,ok take your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, in the dropdown list, you don't see the product names. You see the attribute values, for the configurable attribute. So there is no way of getting the associated product SKU, because there is no product.
Anyway...the dropdown options are generated in this method `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable::getJsonConfig`.
Inside this, there is this code that gives you the simple associated products `$this->getAllowProducts()` and the line that generates the label of an option is this: `'label'     => $attribute->getLabel(),`. Maybe you can find a way to combine them and get the desired result.